# Cardinal spline on D3 Globe

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to implement a D3 cardinal interpolation on a line which I build from multiple coordinates. Right now it is not working and I am just getting a linear interpolation. Any ideas?

Here is my fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/av0vrwko/). Remember to click on the 'add paths' button at the top ...

This is the piece code that should be generating the spline.

```
var svg = d3.select("#body").select('svg');
  flows = svg.selectAll("path.flow")
    .data(data.features);

  flows.enter().append("svg:path")
    .classed("flow", true)
    .interpolate("cardinal")
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .style("stroke-width", "1px")
    .attr("id", function(d) {
      return d.properties.name.split(' ').join('_')
    });
```

Thank you all for your time!